# Can a JSON element start with a - and be referenced in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I have this JSON which was automatically converted from an xml file, and the elements all start with a '-'. So for example name would be -name.

Heres a sample code:

```
 "Object": {
          "-color": "0xAAAAAA",
          "-lineSize": "4",
          "-letterSymbol": "L"
}
```

Say the Object is in the variable object in js. Is there a way to call-> 
 `object.-color` in order to get the color? That approach doesn't work, but are there any alternatives or do I need to change the JSON object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bracket notation instead:

```
object["-color"]
```

As you've found, keys with `-` or other symbols confuse the javascript parser. So, unless your keys are fully alphanumeric then you will need to use the bracket notation system.

Also, if you need to "drill down" further then you can do this:

```
object["-color"]["descendant"]["etc"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's valid JSON, so to answer the question in the title, yes the name can start with a `-`.  According to [the spec](http://json.org/), the name is a string, which is defined (in part) as being made up of "any UNICODE character"s.

To access it in your case, you need to use the bracket notation, rather than the dot notation:

```
object["-color"]
```